# Datatables maximum number of records fetched in server side laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatables

I'm using Laravel 5 and Datatables https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables . I'm using the basic datatable usage in server side processing. I have 30,000 records and I am getting an 500 Error when fetching. However when I limit the data like 10,000 records,it works fine. Here's my code:

Ajax

```
$('#QuestionList').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: 'api/question/all'
});
```

Laravel

```
public function apiGetQuestions()
{
   $questions = Question::orderBy('sortorder', 'asc')->take(10000)->get();
   return Datatables::of($questions)->make();
}
```

But if I make it

```
$questions = Question::orderBy('sortorder', 'asc')->get();
```

I get

[image]

Is the request getting overloaded?

Comment: Is there anything in your `php_error.log`?

Comment: By the looks of that request your making your probably not doing yourself any favours with using a GET rather than a POST request.

Comment: It could be that your running out of memory for the request I'd say this could be quite likely with that number of records.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line:

```
$questions = Question::orderBy('sortorder', 'asc')->select('*');
```